# Four Columns Match on Different Worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vlookup

Is there a way to find if the combination of 4 column cell values has a match with a different sheet's 4 column cell and display true if the match exists using vlookup? If not what would be the best way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to need to return any value from matching rows, just check for the existence of a four column match. A [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) can accomplish this efficiently and without *Helper* column(s). Any non-zero value can be considered *True* but if you need to show **TRUE** on the worksheet, wrap the formula in an AND function.

Example: You want to check columns A, B, C and D from Sheet1 with columns M, N, J and K from Sheet2. In an unused column to the right of the data on Sheet1, use this formula,

```
=AND(COUNIFS(Sheet2!M:M, A2, Sheet2!N:N, B2, Sheet2!J:J, C2, Sheet2!K:K, D2))
```

Fill down as necessary. Any four column matches will show **TRUE**; non-matching rows will show **FALSE**.

With some absolute column references, this formula could also be used in a Conditional Formatting rule to highlight matching rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to combine the 4 columns and then have true next to them if they match in the other 4 columns you can do:

`=A2&B2&C2&D2` in the cells next to each of the 4 columns. In my example I have just had them in the first 4 columns and with a title row in the first row.

Do that for both sets of columns. Drag the formula down to the entire column. Then next to the one you want to find a match next to do `=Sheet2!E2=E2`

That is assuming that the second set of 4 columns is in sheet2 with the same first 4 columns used. Then it will be true or false if they exist in both.

Comment: So does the combination have to be on the same cell range or combination on the other worksheet too? Or it will look through all combinations?

Comment: The order of the combination can be different but it the columns need to match so the data order needs to be the same. You can combine anything really. ALl it does is it puts the data into a single string then checks to see if the string matches somewhere else.